# Angular how to delay/stagger the animation inside of child components

Tags: angular, angular-animations

I have a child component with animations

**child.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'child',
  animations:[
    // animations
   ]
})
export class ChildComponent { ... }
```

And a parent component, which has 2 of the child components in the html

**parent.component.hmtl.ts**

```
...
<child></child>
<child></child>
...
```

[**Stackblitz Example**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-exsnzr)

What I want to achieve is to stagger the animations of the child components in the parent component. Therefore second child component should start animation after X seconds.

[animateChild()](https://angular.io/api/animations/animateChild) sounds like it might work but I cant figure out how I can use it. Is that the right solution? If so an example would be really helpful.

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**: animateChild() does not seem to work for this case. Appearantly it only works on animations that are defined in the parent component.

**EDIT2**: I think there might be a workaround by adding a delay to the animations inside of the child components.

**child.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'child',
  animations:[
    animate(x),
    // animations
   ]
})
export class ChildComponent { ... }
```

The x would be a variable that would increase for every child component.
This workaround looks kinda messy to me

**EDIT3:** the anwers so far are more or less the solution i mentioned in my second edit. While those do work I still consider those as workarounds.

I am looking for a solution that only involves the parent component therefore the child component should stay the way it is like in [this non working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-q75u1p?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: Can you create stackblitz demo?

Comment: i added a stackblitz demo

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As per angular documentation in animation function.

> The second argument, delay, has the same syntax as duration. For
>   example:
>
> Wait for 100ms and then run for 200ms: '0.2s 100ms'

Full reading [here](https://angular.io/guide/animations#transitions-and-timing)

So, our goal is to pass the second parameter something like this

```
animate('2000ms {{delay}}ms'
```

first, lets add input parameter to your child component so we can accept the input values from the parent ones:

```
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() delay: number = 0;
  constructor() { }    
}
```

Now, lets pass down the parameter value form the parent component

```
<p>child1</p>
<app-child [delay]="0"></app-child>

<p>child2</p>
<app-child [delay]="1000"></app-child>
<p>child2 should have a delay</p>
```

In your child component we need to pass this parameter to the animation trigger so it would look like this

```
<p [@childAnimation]="{value:'',params:{delay:delay}}">
    IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII
</p>
```

And finally we can change our animation to support this parameter value

```
animations: [
    trigger('childAnimation', [
      transition(':enter', [
        animate('2000ms {{delay}}ms', style({ transform: 'translateX(80%)' })),
        animate('2000ms', style({ transform: 'translateX(0)' })),
      ], { params: { delay: 0 } })
    ])
  ]
```

all good now, you should working delay to the inputs now.

[Check out demo here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-d18tuz)

Comment: this answer does not really fullfill my expectation(see edit3) but it works and looks like it is the most clean one

Comment: @Flyii as per your edit3 the above solution works with parent one too

Comment: im not sure what you mean. Your solution introduces an input to the child component and modifying its animation with it. i was hoping for a solution which would look like this non working example:  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-q75u1p?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: @Flyii that is not possible as far as I know, the problem is you do not know how many directive has been reused.

Answer (score 4):

*These aren't the only options, but they are ones I know. Angular 7 compatible.*

[Working Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7-master-lw42rp)

## Option 1: Host Binding & States

Within your child component, declare your animation state as a host-binding.

```
@HostBinding('@animationState') animstate : string = 'preanimationstate';
```

Then use a normal input within your child component to get the delay:

```
@Input('delay') delay : number;
```

Pass in the delay like so:

```
<child-component [delay]="500"></child-component>
```

So now in the OnInit you can just use a timeout:

```
let self = this;
window.setTimeout(function () {
    self.animstate = 'newstate';
}, self.delay);
```

**Reasoning:**

It seems like animate child could also be your saving grace, but this way is pretty straight forward and simple as well. Hope it helps.

## Option 2: Move animation to HostComponent and manually apply state

You could also move your animation definition (if it is using states and transitions), from **child.component.ts** to **parent.component.ts**, then start all of your child components off with an initial state modifier like this:

```
<child [@animstate]="initial"></child>>
```

Then get your elements via **ViewChildren**:

```
@ViewChildren(ChildComponent) childComponents as QueryList<ChildComponent>;
```

This is accessible with **AfterViewInit**. Apply your states within the after view init using a for/each loop and a `window.setTimeout` Function.

Comment: Thank you. Option 1 works perfectly. I actually used the ‘setTimeout’ method with GSAP, and it works well.

Answer (score 2):

Just in case anyone stumbles on this issue again: If you want both animations to play at the same time you simply need to use `group` and `animateChild`. Basically, in the plunker linked in the first post you have to replace `outerTransition` with the following:

```
const outerTransition = transition('void => *', [
  style({opacity: 0}),
  group([
    animate(2000, style({opacity: 1})),
    query('@inner', [
      animateChild()
    ]),
  ]),
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can actually use the **stagger** method, with an animation **query**, to achieve this:

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qnv2py?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

By adding this:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {
  trigger,
  style,
  animate,
  query,
  stagger,
  transition,
} from '@angular/animations';


const transition1 = trigger('listAnimation', [
  transition('* => *', [ // each time the binding value changes
    query(':leave', [
      stagger(-100, [
        animate('0.5s', style({ opacity: 0 }))
      ])
    ], { optional: true }),
    query(':enter', [
      style({ opacity: 0 }),
      stagger(500, [
        animate('0.5s', style({ opacity: 1 }))
      ])
    ], { optional: true })
  ])
])

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  animations: [
    transition1
  ]
})
export class AppComponent {

  items = [];

  showItems() {
    this.items = [0,1,2,3,4];
  }

  hideItems() {
    this.items = [];
  }

  toggle() {
    this.items.length ? this.hideItems() : this.showItems();
   }

}
```

The only modification you will have to use, is to loop out your *child components*, which I would have thought, is what you might be planning to do, anyway?

If not just create a dummy array, with the number of items, matching the number of *child components*, you wish to display.

Notice the negative value of the *leave* value. This actually reverses the order, in which the items disappear.

The key to this technique, is to control the animation, entirely from the parent component.

Leave the *child component* to carry out its own animation.